# Can't suppress warnings on an older GCC

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings

I'm working with some autogenerated code that tends to have lines like

```
void f(int16_t a)
{
    if (a < INT32_MAX)
       ...
}
```

Which obviously produce warnings such as:

```
warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
```

I can't change the GCC command line options, I can just add code before/after the autogenerated stuff, like this:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wtype-limits"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wtautological-constant-out-of-range-compare"

#include "autogenerated.h"

#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Which works nicely on newer GCC versions, but I need to support back to gcc-3.4.6. I can deal with missing `#pragma GCC diagnostic push`, but it seems this warning was bundled with `-Wextra`in previous versions. So, I try to disable it all:

```
// GCC 4.6+ needed for push/pop
#if __GNUC__ > 4 || (__GNUC__ == 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__ >= 6)
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#endif
// Disable warnings about unknown pragmas in case some of the options
// aren't present in the current version
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wpragmas"
// Disable the problematic warnings
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wtautological-constant-out-of-range-compare"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wsign-compare"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wtype-limits"
// Sometimes it is bundled in -Wextra without a specific one, so disable that too
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wextra"
// Disable everything else as well!
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wall"

#include "autogenerated.h"

#if __GNUC__ > 4 || (__GNUC__ == 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__ >= 6)
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
#else
#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wtautological-constant-out-of-range-compare"
#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wsign-compare"
#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wtype-limits"
#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wextra"
#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wall"
#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wpragmas"
#endif
```

And I still get that warning.

---

**EDIT**

After some more looking, seems like this is not possible. `#pragma GCC diagnostic` has been added in `gcc-4.2.4`, and the lines were ignored completely. There was no warning because `-Wpragmas` also is not present in `gcc-3.4.6`.

I'll have to resort to changing/tricking the generator to not create warnable code.

Comment: Reading the gcc manual suggests `-w` might do what you need.

Comment: Hrm.. Do you know how to use `-w` in `#pragma diagnostic`? It only deals with warning flags (starting with `-W`) and only has options for `ignored`, `warning` and `error`.  I can't change the command line (better chance of changing the generator, but I really don't want to do that).

Comment: 1) Why don't use use a recent gcc? They have improved a lot since the 3.x  versions 2) Why are the warnings causing you a problems? If you're compiling someone else's code I don't see how this is an issue.

Comment: 1) Not my decision. It works currently, so little chance of that changing soon (it's not a trivial change). 2a) Because `-Werror`, 2b) I end up getting thousands of those due to how it's included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `#pragma GCC system_header`.

From manual:

> The header files declaring interfaces to the operating system and runtime libraries often cannot be written in strictly conforming C.  Therefore, GCC gives code found in system headers special treatment.  All warnings, other than those generated by ‘#warning’ (see Diagnostics), are suppressed while GCC is processing a system header.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Please edit your question to improve formatting. The code example and a citation can be formatted with edit tools. So the question gets easier to read and understand.